# Magento 2 post params don't have the image file

Tags: magento2

I'm developing an admin grid list. In the edit form i have an image field, but when i save it it does't appear in:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
```

and in:

```
$data = $this->getRequest();
```

I can see:

```
  protected 'postParams' => 
    object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[73]
      private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
        array (size=9)
          'form_key' => string 'gSliqxNCIitA25WV' (length=16)
          'entity_id' => string '9' (length=1)
          'name' => string 'bla' (length=3)
          'surname' => string 'bla' (length=3)
          'email' => string 'bla' (length=3)
          'company' => string 'bla' (length=3)
          'note' => string 'bla' (length=3)
          'store_id' => string '1' (length=1)
          'url_key' => string 'bla' (length=3)
  protected 'fileParams' => 
    object(Zend\Stdlib\Parameters)[74]
      private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
        array (size=1)
          'image' => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
  protected 'version' => string '1.1' (length=3)
  protected 'headers' => 
    object(Zend\Http\Headers)[75]
      protected 'pluginClassLoader' => 
        object(Zend\Http\HeaderLoader)[78]
          protected 'plugins' => 
            array (size=55)
              ...
```

And maybe i can get the image from the 'fileParams', but i don't know how.
I already tried:
 `var_dump($this->getRequest()->getParams());`

so, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as your post data does not contain the information about the image file. It is stored in **$_FILES**.

So, Use Magento-2's Uploader To upload the file. Collect the post params in **Request** (lets say in **$data** ) and store the uploaded file name (from uploader result) in the $data under the same key as your field name in database.

Use this Modified **$data** for saving.

Answer (score 1):

First set form in `<form enctype="multipart/form-data">` and Check controller file in like

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && strlen($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
 echo $_FILES['image']['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the information for my issue.

I got that in  `$_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to **get image data in controller**.

```
$bgImage = $this->getRequest()->getFiles('bg_image'); // replace with Image field name
$fileName = ($bgImage && array_key_exists('name', $bgImage)) ? $bgImage['name'] : null;
            if ($bgImage && $fileName) {
                try {
                    $uploader = $this->_objectManager->create(
                        'Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\Uploader',
                        ['fileId' => 'bg_image']
                    );

                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);

                $imageAdapterFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')
                    ->create();

                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
                $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);

                $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
                    ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);

                $result = $uploader->save(
                    $mediaDirectory
                        ->getAbsolutePath()
                );
                $model->setBgImage($result['file']);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                if ($e->getCode() == 0) {
                    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
```